# template file/ index.html file load when loading login page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using adminLTD+angular js template. i tried to load login page when application load. but issue is login page loading with sidebar menu, footer and header. That's login page load on the index.html (template file). how i fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Do you have two templates ? One for the login and another one for the sidebar menu ? It looks like you have the side bar structure in the index file, and you are trying to call the login page inside of the same index file. I suggest you to remove the side bar stuff from the index file and call it only when the user logs in.

Comment: no i have only one template. it loads after login successfully. login page is single html page. problem is that template load for login page. i do not want template file elements for login page.